# C# Leaflet how do i properly post data from view to controller using ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, leaflet

currently i keep getting the alert request failed whenever i try to pass back data from view to controller.

leafletLats and leafletLngs are an array, but im not sure of the datatype. They are derived from coord which is of type LatLng[].

may i know what is causing the Post method to not pass through? is it the problems in the controller?

in View

```
routeControl.on('routeselected', function (e) {
            var coord = e.route.coordinates;
            var name = e.route.name;
            var leafletLats = coord.map(function(point) {
                return [point.lat];
            });
            var leafletLngs = coord.map(function(point) {
                return [point.lng];
            });

            alert('Array size = ' + coord.length + '\nCoordinates: \n' + leafletLats);
            alert('Array size = ' + coord.length + '\nCoordinates: \n' + leafletLngs);
            //alert('Array size = ' + coord.length + '\nCoordinates: \n' + coord.join('\n'));

            $.ajax({ 
                type: 'Post',
                url: '/Map/GetRouteCoordinates',
                data: JSON.stringify(leafletLats),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) { 
                    alert(`Request passed!`);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(`Request failed!`);
                }
            });
```

in controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetRouteCoordinates(MyModel test)
        {
            //do something with the result
            Debug.WriteLine("data passed back");



            return View();
        }


    public class MyModel
    {
        public List<MyModel_Value> latList { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyModel_Value
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }        
    }
```

Comment: I can't code C# but are you sure that `data: JSON.stringify(leafletLats),` is type LatLng[] in the conrtoller and not String, because you stringify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did some modification and changing the data to `data: JSON.stringify({ arr: stringifiedArr })` works for me